# Render problems (black, purple and blue effects) in old GPU and Unity3D 5.6 project on Unity 2018

Tags: unity, shaders, rendering, gpu

Well, I have a PC that has a GPU from 2009, and now I have some problems with a fork.

The project was on Unity 5 (2015) and I have upgraded it to Unity 2018.1.0, without any problems.

But some times, when I updated scripts or changed something in the scene the problem appeared.

Is a rendering problem that only occurs in DirectX 10 (my GPU is a GeForce 9600 that supports up to DX 9.0c, so I don't underatand how this is capable of running DX 10). Because, if I run with `-force-opengl` all runs fine.

I can go back, but the problem is in the Library folder, because if I use "Assets > Reimport all" or I remove this folder, the problem dissapeared (before, not now).

This is the problem:

https://i.gyazo.com/eb9199b8590fddf416a8323331e20856.mp4

Researching I have worsened it:

https://i.gyazo.com/dbc5d5f19a845ec77e54d64e3cba85cc.mp4

https://i.gyazo.com/939c8fdf5fd4d68e434958e93e68da14.mp4

As you can see, sometimes the problem is blue and purple, and other times is completely black.

The last problem remembers me to: https://forum.unity.com/threads/black-textures-on-some-devices-android-versions.195328/

I have builded the project and there isn't any problem, so the problem is somewhere in the Editor or with a UNITY_EDITOR preprocessor directive.

I don't know what I have to do to fix this. Is like this is very random.

Any help?

Comment: GPUs with incomplete DirectX 10, 11, 12 support, missing a few obligatory features to qualify, can have features equivalent to the ones found in later DirectX versions enabled in their OpenGL API through extensions. OpenGL has a more granular feature system where you can use DirectX 12 equivalent features even through the OpenGL 1.5 API from 2003. Which means that sometimes you can access more features through OpenGL than DirectX on the same GPU, especially on older Windows versions that are "banned" from using newer DirectX APIs.

Comment: From the looks of it my guess is a reflection probe or light map texture issue. Try changing the reflection probes settings, light probes, AO? (if you have). One of the texture format or texture sample function in the shader(s) must not be supported properly.

Comment: Thanks for both answers, well, I have builded the game and there isn't any problem. So, it has relation with some setting in Unity Editor, or maybe with some preprocessor directive (UNITY_EDITOR).